# HTTP Post on Google App Engine only works half of the time

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, urlfetch

I have used URLFetch class to do HTTP Post in Google App engine to my php file (on some different website).

This is what I have

```
try{
byte[] data = ("EMAIL=bo0@gmail.com&TITLE=evolution&COMMENT=comments&PRICE=5000").getBytes("UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("http://www.box.com/nost.php");
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.POST);
request.setPayload(data);
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request);
}
```

now this seems to work perfectly fine when I deploy locally.
However, when I publish on google app engine, this only works half of the time.
(ie. even with exact same data, i press post, more than once, it can be either error or success)

Since I am not changing any data, this seems to be totally random.
Can anyone give me advice why this is happening?

EDIT: this is a working code
It seems like my php was blocking http request that gae is making , some of the time. I fixed by using recursion inside catch block to keep trying until succeed.

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.php");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writer.write("EMAIL="+URLEncoder.encode("sam@gmail.com", "UTF-8")+
"&TITLE="+URLEncoder.encode("myTitle", "UTF-8")+
"&PRICE="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(10000), "UTF-8"));
writer.close();

if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
// OK
return true;
} else {
// Server returned HTTP error code.
//keep retrying until you succeed!! fighting!!
return newPost(postComponent);
}
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
//ah dam probably server is down so you went stack overflow I give up
return false;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".  Define "error".  I could give you half a dozen answers, but right now I can't make more than a wile guess.  I can't even tell if you mean HTTP error codes or exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the URLFetch service, I'd strongly recommend that you use java.net instead.

In my experience, this is the way to go. I've setup test cases before where I loop through a collection and make large numbers of POST requests to a remote server and then write the count and output to the browser so I can see how many succeeded and how many failed.

The results were interesting. I saw exceptions in my logs, and I thought to myself, "Oh great, more wasted time trying to figure out why the network sucks!".  Well, I looked at my results for a hundred and a thousand test cases, and all were a success.

After digging into the exceptions, it was clear that the code actually tries to make the request a 2nd time if it, for instance, gets a 500 response from the server! This is why all my cases were successful, despite some 500 errors!

This was exactly what I was looking for, since it avoided the need for me to write my own error handlers for server issues or minor network issues, the library took care of that for me.

[java.net - HTTPURLConnection](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet) has proven to be quite reliable when sending data to a server:

> The following example makes an HTTP POST request to a URL with some form data:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

// ...
        String message = URLEncoder.encode("my message", "UTF-8");

        try {

            // this is your url that you're posting to
            URL url = new URL("http://www.box.com/nost.php");

            // create and open the connection using POST 
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            // this is your data that you're sending to the server! 
            writer.write("EMAIL=bo0@gmail.com&TITLE=evolution&COMMENT=comments&PRICE=5000");

            writer.close();

            // this is where you can check for success/fail. 
             // Even if this doesn't properly try again, you could make another 
              // request in the ELSE for extra error handling! :)        
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // OK
            } else {
                // Server returned HTTP error code.
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
```

Remember, you're not making a request to a php file, you're making a request to a server. The file type makes no difference as it's all HTTP under the hood. Hope this helps!

I edited the example from Google so that it uses your remote endpoint and your query string data.

Comment: I have read your answer somewhere in other post but it did not help me at all, I am trying to make http request on php file, not trying to read an xml file.

Comment: java.net isn't just for reading XML, it's for fetching content from a remote server. It could be HTML, CSS, JavaSript, XML, CSV files, or just sending query parameters. It's a general high level tool for getting data from A to B. This is just an example, and it's up to you to tailor it to your unique data set. The point you're missing here is that this has some built in failover, which it sounds like you need if you're encountering a lot of failure. Can you elaborate by what you mean by it didn't help? What kind of errors are you actually getting?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know it can be used for sending query parameters. I am little lost on how to change your code to make it send query parameters.
I am trying to figure out what is causing the problem, but I am not sure how I can see the log since it is already deployed to the app engine.

Comment: It seems like when I was using my old code, my php is giving a response that is not 200. This is driving me crazy Arg!!!

Comment: This should give you more of the power that you need. I also suggest filling in the catch blocks for better logging. When I ran my tests, what I did is wrapped this in a for loop and ran it 10 times, then 100, then 1000, just to see how reliable it was. Keep in mind that there still may be problems either with your network or on the PHP server. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This does not seem to have solved my problem ( exactly same runs fine on local deploy but randomly rejected when deployed on app engine).
but you just gave me alternative solution which is just keep retrying.
I will try that!!

Comment: I'm curious to know how it works out. You could use some kind of recursion algorithm from your catch and else block, if need be. Also, another thing you might try, to rule out Java+appengine as the culprit, what happens if you put the URL in your browser and hit it 10 times? Does it still fail, or does it go through 100%?

Comment: my PHP URL works 100% of the time. (from my computer) but seems like it is blocking some request when app engine request it.

and yes, it works perfect fine, I used recursion inside my catch block, and only return false (probably stack overflow) on other catch block.